# What sort of updates do ELB properties support (for CloudFormation)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudformation

Question: **What type of updates do each ELB property support?**

I'm reading through the ELB CF docs:

AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html

On the page it states "**This type supports updates**".

The only property that goes into detail is this one:

> SecurityGroups Required: No.
>
> Type: A list of security groups assigned to your load balancer within
>   your virtual private cloud (VPC).
>
> Update requires: no interruption

No other properties mention what type of update they trigger.

Am I missing something in the documentation? Is there a default update action for the other properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the response from AlastairC@AWS on my forum post:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=139722

> Updating the following properties triggers a replacement of an ELB.
>   All other properties will not trigger replacement:
>
> - AvailabilityZones
> - HealthCheck
> - Scheme
> - Subnets

The AvailabilityZones/Subnets changes make sense.

I can even live with the Scheme changes.

I'm not thrilled with the fact that if you change any HealthCheck values this will cause a new ELB to be created (and thus require DNS changes).

At least we've got an answer!

Also, they mentioned the AWS docs will be updated:

> Thanks so much for bringing this to our attention! We are working on a
>   fix to our documentation and will post an update to this thread once
>   the fix is rolled out.